# Guardar Link con PHP en BBDD MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito algo de ayuda, mi caso es el siguiente:

En una cantidad X de texto, busca un URL y lo modifica de tal forma que funcione y me lleve a la página que le corresponda, el problema está en guardarlo, ya que cuando hago el `INSERT` o el `UPDATE`, me lo guarda de una forma errónea que es

en la etiqueta html: `<a href="<mi_dominio><link_de_la_web>"><link_de_la_web><a/>`

¿Cómo haría para que se almacene todo el texto más esa etiqueta también con su respectivo `target=_blank`?

Comment: En mi experiencia nunca me ha hecho falta guardar una etiqueta entera de html en la base de datos, creo que muy muy especial tiene que ser el caso para hacerlo. ¿Porque no simplemente guardas los parámetros que quieres y pones el link como html o un echo de php? Almacenas menos información y solucionas el problema. ¿Es posible?

Comment: En si no, ya que el texto que se almacena tiene, texto en negrita, alineacion, parrafos..., asi que guarda todo ese `HTML` incluido el enlace como si fuera texto ejempo: <p><b> hola mundo</b></p>, algo asi se almacena

Comment: Vale, retomando tu flujo, 1º obtienes un texto mas o menos grande. 2º, buscas ahí un PEDAZO/TROZO de string que contiene el enlace, desde la apertura de tu etiqueta HTML hasta el cierre. 3º Quieres almacenar ese enlace a modo de string integramente en la base de datos.  4º Quieres agregar al enlace html un nuevo atributo pero desde PHP, tratando todo el enlace HTML como un solo string ¿Voy bien encaminado? Eso entiendo, si es así, lo investigo e intento decirte algo pronto :). Te agreadecería si puedes mostrar algo mas de código o lógica :)

Comment: 1º correcto 2º busco link dentro de las etiquetas `HTML` que me genera en si son parrafos, negrita, saltos, de linea, 3º una vez encontrado el link (que hasta ahi lo hace bien), lo sustituyo por `<a href="link_encontrado" target="_blank">link_contrado</a>`, todo eso sin necesidad de guardarlo, lo hace bien, el problema esta en guardarlo que no lo guarda como se deberia, el texto del link (lo que esta dento de la etiqueta `<a>`, lo pone bien, el lio esta en el `href`) Gracias :)

Comment: Vale, todo comprendido. Creo que el problema son las comillas.
Me surge la duda
Podrías mostrar COMO CONSTRUYES la sentencia SQL, es decir, como delimitas el contenido de la sentencia, entre que tipo de comillas el contenido que sustituyes, y éste a su vez, como lo almacenas en la variable.

Cuando añades el enlace ```<a href="link_encontrado" target="_blank">link_contrado</a>```, este puede digámoslo así, "invertir o cerrar" el escapado del código por esas comillas del atributo. Es como si (por ejemplo) interpretara ```link_encontrado ``` como código php. ¿Podría ser?

Comment: La sentencia sería `UPDATE entradas set texto='<texto con el link editado> WHERE id= $id;'` más o menos es si la sentencia obviamente hay más campos en la tabla, aunque bueno ahora mismo he logrado algo, misteriosamente en todo el texto que se genera con etiquetas `HTML` incluidas he cambiado el tipo de comilla por un tilde invertida ** ` ** es esa y bueno ahora guarda bien el link el problema es que hoara no me redirecciona a la pagina que le corresponde, me lleva dentro del dominio

Comment: Te paso esta documentación por si te resulta útil, intentaré realizar un ejemplo por mi mismo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php/3446286#3446286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tema solucionado he el problema estaba en como se interpetaba todo a la hora de cambiir el link forma texto en etiqueta `<a/>` he aqui la solución:

```
function corrige_enlaces($string){
    $expre="https://";
    $pos=strpos($string, $expre);
    if ($pos === false) {


    } else {

        $pos2=strpos($string," ",$pos);
        $enlace = substr($string, $pos);

        $del_text = substr($string, $pos2);

        $enlace= str_replace ($del_text, "", $enlace);

        $string =  str_replace ($enlace, "<a href=$enlace target='_blank'>".$enlace."</a>", $string);

    }

return $string;

}
```

es probable que se pueda hacer mejor pero esto es lo que me funciona ahora.